# How to create a log in using another site database?

Tags: php, jquery

We have a website running and my boss wanted to use a WordPress website as a cover.

I am trying to create a log in in WordPress using our existing user database. So that when the user log in in WordPress, they will be redirect to our current website.

Any suggestions on how should I approach this?

I tried using jQuery `$.post` but it didn't work out well for external links.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this securely, you will probably need to implement something server-side. For example, log into the WordPress site and then if that is successful, redirect the user to your current website.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the login logic and if login is good proceed to your website. Something like this:

```
<?php
     /* Your login logic */
     if login = 'success'
     {
        $urlToRedirect = 'https://yourwebsite.com'
        header('Location: '.$urlToRedirect);
     }
     exit;
?>
```